# Silverstripe - creating page type tables throws error

Tags: silverstripe

I am having an issue when any tables are created for a particular page type, whether I add `$db` or `$has_one` all pages using that page type break... I don't understand what's happening or how to resolve it.

This is the model I'm using

**Content.php**

```
class Content extends Page {

    private static $db = array(
        'TranslatedTitle' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'TranslatedContent' => 'HTMLText'
    );

    public function getCMSFields(){

        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

        $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Content.Translation', array(
            TextField::create('TranslatedTitle'),
            HTMLEditorField::create('TranslatedContent')
            )
        );

        return $fields;
    }
}

class Content_Controller extends Page_Controller {}
```

Here is the error that comes in,
I've spaced it out a little so it's readable

```
[08-Sep-2016 10:07:00] Error at framework/model/connect/DBConnector.php line 55:
Uncaught SS_DatabaseException: Couldn't run query:

SELECT DISTINCT
    "SiteTree_versions"."ClassName",
    "SiteTree_versions"."LastEdited",
    "SiteTree_versions"."Created",
    "SiteTree_versions"."URLSegment",
    "SiteTree_versions"."Title",
    "SiteTree_versions"."MenuTitle",
    "SiteTree_versions"."Content_versions",
    "SiteTree_versions"."MetaDescription",
    "SiteTree_versions"."ExtraMeta",
    "SiteTree_versions"."ShowInMenus",
    "SiteTree_versions"."ShowInSearch",
    "SiteTree_versions"."Sort",
    "SiteTree_versions"."HasBrokenFile",
    "SiteTree_versions"."HasBrokenLink",
    "SiteTree_versions"."ReportClass",
    "SiteTree_versions"."CanViewType",
    "SiteTree_versions"."CanEditType",
    "SiteTree_versions"."Version",
    "SiteTree_versions"."ParentID",
    "Page_versions"."SiteID",
    "Content_versions"."TranslatedTitle",
    "Content_versions"."TranslatedContent",
    "SiteTree_versions"."ID",
CASE WHEN
    "SiteTree_versions"."ClassName"
IS NOT NULL THEN
    "SiteTree_versions"."ClassName"
ELSE
    'SiteTree'
END AS
    "RecordClassName",
    "SiteTree_versions"."RecordID",
    "SiteTree_versions"."WasPublished",
    "SiteTree_versions"."AuthorID",
    "SiteTree_versions"."PublisherID"

FROM
    "SiteTree_versions"
LEFT JOIN
    "Page_versions"
ON
    "Page_versions"."ID" = "SiteTree_versions"."ID"
LEFT JOIN
    "Content_versions"
ON
    "Content_versions"."ID" = "SiteTree_versions"."ID"

WHERE ("SiteTree_versions"."ClassName" IN (?))
AND ("SiteTree_versions"."RecordID" = ?)

ORDER BY
    "SiteTree_versions"."LastEdited" DESC,
    "SiteTree_versions"."Version" DESC

42S22-1054: Unknown column 'SiteTree_versions.Content_versions' in 'field list'
```

I haven't got this anywhere on any other page types...  Why is this happening?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the fact that I have a class named Content as well as a table column with that same name?

Comment: That should be easy to test. Rename your Page to `ContentPage`, run `dev/build` and check again? `Content` seems to be a really bad name for a page-type anyways :)

Comment: Aah! Yeah you're right, that was it! So now I know to avoid using any names SS uses lol - Thanks!